# animated submit button

Tags: css, animation, input, submit

Is thre a way to create such effects like in the link below using `input[type="submit"]`? I am aware that I can't use `input[type="submit"]:after`.

The link: https://codepen.io/sazzad/pen/yNNNJG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use gradient and animate `background-size` and/or `background-position`:

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  border:2px solid pink;
  padding:5px 20px;
  font-size:30px;
  background:linear-gradient(pink,pink) center/100% 0px no-repeat;
  transition:0.5s all linear;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
```

Another example:

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  border:2px solid pink;
  padding:5px 20px;
  font-size:30px;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,pink 0,pink 4px,transparent 4px, transparent 8px) center/0px 100%  no-repeat;
  transition:0.5s all linear;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
```